# How to setup SSJS to create data extension from existing template?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

My audience data extension has hidden data types, such as `LongNumber` and `Decimal` (set to more than 18 digits for example 20.15), these are fields that were appended from the audience attributes.

Via UI I can create a new data extension from a template and choose this audience as a model, even with no rights to change the predefined fields and types, just adding new ones.

I am running an automation that I need data extension model as the audience DE mentioned above, instead of creating manually I tried a simple script in a page creates the DEs.

```
var dataExt = DataExtension.Init("dataExt");

    var sdeObj = {
      CustomerKey : "SOME_CUSTOMERKEY_HERE",
      Name : "SOME_NAME_HERE",       
      Fields : [
          { "Name" : "Field Name1", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 254, "IsRequired" : true, "IsPrimaryKey" : true },
          { "Name" : "Field Name2", "FieldType" : "EmailAddress",  "MaxLength" : 254 },
          { "Name" : "Field Name3", "FieldType" : "Decimal", "MaxLength" : 23.15 },
          { "Name" : "Field Name4", "FieldType" : "LongNumber", "MaxLength" : 100 },

      ],
      SendableInfo : {
          Field : { "Name" : "SubscriberKey", "FieldType" : "Text" },
          RelatesOn : "Subscriber Key"
      }

    };

  var newDE = DataExtension.Add(sdeObj);
```

The point is: there is no LongNumber data type and even the decimal >18. As in the rows below.

> { "Name" : "Field Name3", "FieldType" : "Decimal", "MaxLength" : **23.15**
>   }, 
>   { "Name" : "Field Name4", "FieldType" : "**LongNumber**", "MaxLength" : 100 },

Researching a little, I could find the dev doc *[Create a Data Extension Using an Existing Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_an_existing_template.htm)* however the solution I need can't involve api calls once I have limited admin rigths.

**1** - Does anyone know how to `create a data extension from template` using SSJS?

> OR

**2** - How to create a DE with not listed data types? (e.g.: LongNumber)